# cytoscape.js: Safari does not show simplest graph

Tags: cytoscape.js

I wrote html page with simplest graph. It contain only one node.
In FireFox it's showed well, but Safari (5.1.7 fo Windows) does not show it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cy" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  $(function(){ // on dom ready
    $("#cy").cytoscape({ 
      elements: [ { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'a', name: 'Adam' } } ],
      ready: function(){
      }
    });
  alert('END');
  }); // on dom ready
</script>
```

Moreover I use function alert('END') to check that everything is ok.
And FireFox shows message 'END', but Safari does not.
Only if I remove line 'elements: [ ... ]', then Safari shows message 'END'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape.js uses HTML5 technologies such that only A-grade autoupdated browsers are supported. Safari 5 is very old, and I don't think it's supported on Windows anymore.